# Magento 2 Call Rest api issue : "\"%fieldName\" is required. Enter and try again.",

Tags: magento2, magento2-api

I am trying to call Magento 2 Quote rest api,

```
 <route url="/V1/carts/mine/coupons/:couponCode" method="PUT">
        <service class="Magento\Quote\Api\CouponManagementInterface" method="set"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="self" />
        </resources>
        <data>
            <parameter name="cartId" force="true">%cart_id%</parameter>
        </data>
    </route>
```

but i get issue like `"\"%fieldName\" is required. Enter and try again.",`

here is the screenshot.
[image]

Can any one help me to resolve this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If using PUT `/V1/carts/mine/coupons/:couponCode` or GET `/V1/carts/mine/coupons`, we don't need to pass `cart_id`.

`cart_id` will be overridden by `vendor/magento/module-quote/etc/di.xml`

```
<type name="Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\ParamsOverrider">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="paramOverriders" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="%cart_id%" xsi:type="object">Magento\Quote\Model\Webapi\ParamOverriderCartId\Proxy</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

**Note:** try to change GET to PUT. You're using wrong method?

Comment: yes, right. but still result is same. i have remove the cart_id from param. but no result. any other suggestion.

Comment: Did you try to change GET to PUT?